# FOSS alternatives to Acrobat Connect Pro

Tags: meetings

I was wondering if anyone tested FOSS alternatives to [Acrobat Connect Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatconnectpro/), and what is your feedback?

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the features of Connect Pro, but [Big Blue Button](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/) may provide some of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used but heard that [DimDim](http://www.dimdim.com/) is really good..

Comment: Dim Dim has shutdown. http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2011/01/110106.jsp

Comment: Heck i answered it 2 years back. Didn't even remember it. Thanks for the update though. :-)

Comment: I know, sorry. I didn't mean anything by it.